# Excel VBA Macro to copy a macro

Tags: excel, vba

### SOLVED. Solution at bottom!

Hopefully you brainiacs can help me out as I've apparently reached the limit of my programming capabilities.

I am looking for a way to write a VBA sub which duplicates another VBA Sub, but replace the name and another input. The case in details:

I am trying to build an Excel template for the organization, which will allow the users to inport/export data to/from Access databases (.accdb), as the end-users reluctance towards using real databases (as opposed to excel lists) apparently lies in their inability to extract/submit the data to/from Excel, where they are comfortable working with the data.

The challenge is, that users who don't know how to link to Access, for sure don't know anything about VBA code. Hence, I have created a worksheet from which the users selects a database using a file-path, table, password, set filters, define where to copy/insert datasets, fields to import etc. A Macro then handles the rest.

However, I want to create a macro which allows the user to create additional database links. As it is right now, this would require the user to open VBE and copy two macros and change one line of code... but that is a recipe for disaster. So how can I add a button to the sheet that copies the code I have written and rename the macro?

... I was considering if using a function, but cannot get my head around how that should Work.

Does it make sense? Any ideas/ experiences? Is there a completely different way around it that I haven't considered?

I'd really appreciate your inputs - even if this turns out to be impossible.

Edit:
Macro Man, you asked for the code - it's rather long due to all the user input fields, so I was trying to save you Guys for it since the code in and of itself is working fine...

```
Sub GetData1()
' Click on Tools, References and select
' the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.0 Library

 Dim DBFullName As String
 Dim Connect As String, Source As String
 Dim Connection As ADODB.Connection
 Dim Recordset As ADODB.Recordset
 Dim Col As Integer
 Dim DBInfoLocation As Range
 Dim PW As String
 Dim WSforData As String
 Dim CellforData As String
 Dim FieldList As Integer

'******************************
'Enter location for Database conectivity details below:
'******************************
 Set DBInfoLocation = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DBLinks").Range("C15:I21")
 FieldList = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DBLinks").Range("P1").Value
'******************************

' Define data location
 WSforData = DBInfoLocation.Rows(4).Columns(1).Value
 CellforData = DBInfoLocation.Rows(5).Columns(1).Value

'Set filters
 Dim FilField1, FilField2, FilFieldA, FilFieldB, FilFieldC, FilFieldD, FilFieldE, FilOperator1, FilOperator2, FilOperatorA, FilOperatorB, FilOperatorC, FilOperatorD, FilOperatorE, FilAdMth1, FilAdMthA, FilAdMthB, FilAdMthC, FilAdMthD As String
 Dim Filtxt1, Filtxt2, FiltxtA, FiltxtB, FiltxtC, FiltxtD, FiltxtE As String
 Dim ExtFld1, ExtFld2, ExtFld3, ExtFld4, ExtFld5, ExtFld6, ExtFld7, ExtFld As String
 Dim FilCnt, FilCntA As Integer
 Dim FilVar1 As String

 'Set DB field names
 FilField1 = DBInfoLocation.Rows(1).Columns(5).Value
 FilField2 = DBInfoLocation.Rows(2).Columns(5).Value
 FilFieldA = DBInfoLocation.Rows(3).Columns(5).Value
 FilFieldB = DBInfoLocation.Rows(4).Columns(5).Value
 FilFieldC = DBInfoLocation.Rows(5).Columns(5).Value
 FilFieldD = DBInfoLocation.Rows(6).Columns(5).Value
 FilFieldE = DBInfoLocation.Rows(7).Columns(5).Value

 'Set filter operators
 FilOperator1 = DBInfoLocation.Rows(1).Columns(6).Value
 FilOperator2 = DBInfoLocation.Rows(2).Columns(6).Value
 FilOperatorA = DBInfoLocation.Rows(3).Columns(6).Value
 FilOperatorB = DBInfoLocation.Rows(4).Columns(6).Value
 FilOperatorC = DBInfoLocation.Rows(5).Columns(6).Value
 FilOperatorD = DBInfoLocation.Rows(6).Columns(6).Value
 FilOperatorE = DBInfoLocation.Rows(7).Columns(6).Value


  'Run through criteria to find VarType(FilCrit1) (the Dimension data type) for the criteria field and set the appropriate data type for the filter
  currentLoad = IIf(IsNumeric(DBInfoLocation.Rows(1).Columns(7).Value), CDbl(FilCrit1), IIf((DBInfoLocation.Rows(1).Columns(7).Value = "True" Or DBInfoLocation.Rows(1).Columns(7).Value = "False"), CBool(FilCrit1), IIf(IsDate(DBInfoLocation.Rows(1).Columns(7).Value), CDate(FilCrit1), CStr(FilCrit1))))
  currentLoad = IIf(IsNumeric(DBInfoLocation.Rows(2).Columns(7).Value), CDbl(FilCrit2), IIf((DBInfoLocation.Rows(2).Columns(7).Value = "True" Or DBInfoLocation.Rows(2).Columns(7).Value = "False"), CBool(FilCrit2), IIf(IsDate(DBInfoLocation.Rows(2).Columns(7).Value), CDate(FilCrit2), CStr(FilCrit2))))
  currentLoad = IIf(IsNumeric(DBInfoLocation.Rows(3).Columns(7).Value), CDbl(FilCrit3), IIf((DBInfoLocation.Rows(3).Columns(7).Value = "True" Or DBInfoLocation.Rows(3).Columns(7).Value = "False"), CBool(FilCrit3), IIf(IsDate(DBInfoLocation.Rows(3).Columns(7).Value), CDate(FilCrit3), CStr(FilCrit3))))
  currentLoad = IIf(IsNumeric(DBInfoLocation.Rows(4).Columns(7).Value), CDbl(FilCrit4), IIf((DBInfoLocation.Rows(4).Columns(7).Value = "True" Or DBInfoLocation.Rows(4).Columns(7).Value = "False"), CBool(FilCrit4), IIf(IsDate(DBInfoLocation.Rows(4).Columns(7).Value), CDate(FilCrit4), CStr(FilCrit4))))
  currentLoad = IIf(IsNumeric(DBInfoLocation.Rows(5).Columns(7).Value), CDbl(FilCrit5), IIf((DBInfoLocation.Rows(5).Columns(7).Value = "True" Or DBInfoLocation.Rows(5).Columns(7).Value = "False"), CBool(FilCrit5), IIf(IsDate(DBInfoLocation.Rows(5).Columns(7).Value), CDate(FilCrit5), CStr(FilCrit5))))
  currentLoad = IIf(IsNumeric(DBInfoLocation.Rows(6).Columns(7).Value), CDbl(FilCrit6), IIf((DBInfoLocation.Rows(6).Columns(7).Value = "True" Or DBInfoLocation.Rows(6).Columns(7).Value = "False"), CBool(FilCrit6), IIf(IsDate(DBInfoLocation.Rows(6).Columns(7).Value), CDate(FilCrit6), CStr(FilCrit6))))
  currentLoad = IIf(IsNumeric(DBInfoLocation.Rows(7).Columns(7).Value), CDbl(FilCrit7), IIf((DBInfoLocation.Rows(7).Columns(7).Value = "True" Or DBInfoLocation.Rows(7).Columns(7).Value = "False"), CBool(FilCrit7), IIf(IsDate(DBInfoLocation.Rows(7).Columns(7).Value), CDate(FilCrit7), CStr(FilCrit7))))

 'Set Filter criteria
 FilCrit1 = DBInfoLocation.Rows(1).Columns(7).Value
 FilCrit2 = DBInfoLocation.Rows(2).Columns(7).Value
 FilCrit3 = DBInfoLocation.Rows(3).Columns(7).Value
 FilCrit4 = DBInfoLocation.Rows(4).Columns(7).Value
 FilCrit5 = DBInfoLocation.Rows(5).Columns(7).Value
 FilCrit6 = DBInfoLocation.Rows(6).Columns(7).Value
 FilCrit7 = DBInfoLocation.Rows(7).Columns(7).Value

 'Set additional filter-method
 FilAdMth1 = DBInfoLocation.Rows(1).Columns(8).Value
 FilAdMthA = DBInfoLocation.Rows(3).Columns(8).Value
 FilAdMthB = DBInfoLocation.Rows(4).Columns(8).Value
 FilAdMthC = DBInfoLocation.Rows(5).Columns(8).Value
 FilAdMthD = DBInfoLocation.Rows(6).Columns(8).Value

 'Set which fields to extract
 ExtFld1 = DBInfoLocation.Rows(1).Columns(9).Value
 ExtFld2 = DBInfoLocation.Rows(2).Columns(9).Value
 ExtFld3 = DBInfoLocation.Rows(3).Columns(9).Value
 ExtFld4 = DBInfoLocation.Rows(4).Columns(9).Value
 ExtFld5 = DBInfoLocation.Rows(5).Columns(9).Value
 ExtFld6 = DBInfoLocation.Rows(6).Columns(9).Value
 ExtFld7 = DBInfoLocation.Rows(7).Columns(9).Value

    'Filter on query
        'Only criteria of value type string should have single quotation marks around them
    FilCnt = 0
    If FilField1 <> "" Then
        If VarType(FilCrit1) = vbString Then
        Filtxt1 = " WHERE [" & FilField1 & "] " & FilOperator1 & " '" & FilCrit1 & "'"
        Else
        Filtxt1 = " WHERE [" & FilField1 & "] " & FilOperator1 & " " & FilCrit1
        End If
    FilCnt = 1
    End If

    If FilField2 <> "" And FilCnt = 1 Then
        If VarType(FilCrit2) = vbString Then
        Filtxt2 = " " & FilAdMth1 & " [" & FilField2 & "] " & FilOperator2 & " '" & FilCrit2 & "'"
        Else
        Filtxt2 = " " & FilAdMth1 & " [" & FilField2 & "] " & FilOperator2 & " " & FilCrit2
        End If
    FilCnt = 2
    End If

    'Filter on Dataset
    FilCntA = 0
    If FilFieldA <> "" Then
        If VarType(FilCrit3) = vbString Then
        FiltxtA = FilFieldA & " " & FilOperatorA & " '" & FilCrit3 & "'"
        Else
        FiltxtA = FilFieldA & " " & FilOperatorA & " " & FilCrit3
        End If
    FilCntA = 1
    End If

    If FilFieldB <> "" And FilCntA = 1 Then
        If VarType(FilCrit4) = vbString Then
        FiltxtB = " " & FilAdMthA & " " & FilFieldB & " " & FilOperatorB & " '" & FilCrit4 & "'"
        Else
        FiltxtB = " " & FilAdMthA & " " & FilFieldB & " " & FilOperatorB & " " & FilCrit4
        End If
    FilCntA = 2
    End If

    If FilFieldC <> "" And FilCntA = 2 Then
        If VarType(FilCrit5) = vbString Then
        FiltxtC = " " & FilAdMthB & " " & FilFieldC & " " & FilOperatorC & " '" & FilCrit5 & "'"
        Else
        FiltxtC = " " & FilAdMthB & " " & FilFieldC & " " & FilOperatorC & " " & FilCrit5
        End If
    FilCntA = 3
    End If

    If FilFieldD <> "" And FilCntA = 3 Then
        If VarType(FilCrit6) = vbString Then
        FiltxtD = " " & FilAdMthC & " " & FilFieldD & " " & FilOperatorD & " '" & FilCrit6 & "'"
        Else
        FiltxtD = " " & FilAdMthC & " " & FilFieldD & " " & FilOperatorD & " " & FilCrit6
        End If
    FilCntA = 4
    End If

    If FilFieldE <> "" And FilCntA = 4 Then
        If VarType(FilCrit7) = vbString Then
        FiltxtE = " " & FilAdMthD & " " & FilFieldE & " " & FilOperatorE & " '" & FilCrit7 & "'"
        Else
        FiltxtE = " " & FilAdMthD & " " & FilFieldE & " " & FilOperatorE & " " & FilCrit7
        End If
    FilCntA = 5
    End If

    ' Select Fields to Extract
    ExtFld = "*"
    If ExtFld1 <> "" Then
    ExtFld = "[" & ExtFld1 & "]"
    End If

    If ExtFld2 <> "" Then
    ExtFld = "[" & ExtFld1 & "],[" & ExtFld2 & "]"
    End If

    If ExtFld3 <> "" Then
    ExtFld = "[" & ExtFld1 & "],[" & ExtFld2 & "],[" & ExtFld3 & "]"
    End If

    If ExtFld4 <> "" Then
    ExtFld = "[" & ExtFld1 & "],[" & ExtFld2 & "],[" & ExtFld3 & "],[" & ExtFld4 & "]"
    End If

    If ExtFld5 <> "" Then
    ExtFld = "[" & ExtFld1 & "],[" & ExtFld2 & "],[" & ExtFld3 & "],[" & ExtFld4 & "],[" & ExtFld5 & "]"
    End If

    If ExtFld6 <> "" Then
    ExtFld = "[" & ExtFld1 & "],[" & ExtFld2 & "],[" & ExtFld3 & "],[" & ExtFld4 & "],[" & ExtFld5 & "],[" & ExtFld6 & "]"
    End If

    If ExtFld7 <> "" Then
    ExtFld = "[" & ExtFld1 & "],[" & ExtFld2 & "],[" & ExtFld3 & "],[" & ExtFld4 & "],[" & ExtFld5 & "],[" & ExtFld6 & "],[" & ExtFld7 & "]"
    End If


' Database path info

 PW = DBInfoLocation.Rows(3).Columns(1).Value

' Your path will be different
 DBFullName = DBInfoLocation.Rows(1).Columns(1).Value
 DBTable = DBInfoLocation.Rows(2).Columns(1).Value

 ' Open the connection
 Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
 Connect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
 Connect = Connect & "Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & PW & ";"
 Connection.Open ConnectionString:=Connect

' Create RecordSet & Define data to extract
 Set Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset
 With Recordset

    'Get All Field Names by opening the DB, extracting a recordset, entering the field names and closing the dataset
     Source = DBTable
     .Open Source:=Source, ActiveConnection:=Connection
     For ColH = 0 To Recordset.Fields.Count - 1
     ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DBLinks").Range("A1").Offset(ColH + 3, FieldList - 1).Cells.Clear
     ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DBLinks").Range("A1").Offset(ColH + 3, FieldList - 1).Value = Recordset.Fields(ColH).Name
     ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RangeNames").Range("A1").Offset(ColH + 2, (DBInfoLocation.Rows(1).Columns(2).Value) - 1).Cells.Clear
     ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RangeNames").Range("A1").Offset(ColH + 2, (DBInfoLocation.Rows(1).Columns(2).Value) - 1).Value = Recordset.Fields(ColH).Name
     Next
     Set Recordset = Nothing
 End With

     ' Get the recordset, but only extract the field names of those defined in the spreadsheet.
     ' If no fields have been selected, all fields will be extracted.
     Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
     Connect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
     Connect = Connect & "Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & PW & ";"
     Connection.Open ConnectionString:=Connect
     Set Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset
 With Recordset

    If FilCnt = 0 Then 'No filter
        Source = "SELECT " & ExtFld & " FROM " & DBTable
        End If
        ' Filter Data if selected

    If FilCnt = 1 Then
        Source = "SELECT " & ExtFld & " FROM " & DBTable & Filtxt1
        End If

    If FilCnt = 2 Then
        Source = "SELECT " & ExtFld & " FROM " & DBTable & Filtxt1 & Filtxt2
        End If

    .Open Source:=Source, ActiveConnection:=Connection

    If FilCntA = 1 Then
        Recordset.Filter = FiltxtA
        End If

    If FilCntA = 2 Then
        Recordset.Filter = FiltxtA & FiltxtB
        End If

    If FilCntA = 3 Then
        Recordset.Filter = FiltxtA & FiltxtB & FiltxtC
        End If

    If FilCntA = 4 Then
        Recordset.Filter = FiltxtA & FiltxtB & FiltxtC & FiltxtD
        End If

    If FilCntA = 5 Then
        Recordset.Filter = FiltxtA & FiltxtB & FiltxtC & FiltxtD & FiltxtE
        End If
            'Debug.Print Recordset.Filter

' Clear data
 For Col = 0 To Recordset.Fields.Count - 1
    If WSforData <> "" Then
     ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WSforData).Range(CellforData).Offset(0, Col).EntireColumn.Clear
    End If
    'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DBLinks").Range("A1").Offset(Col + 3, FieldList - 1).Cells.Clear
 Next

' Write field names
 For Col = 0 To Recordset.Fields.Count - 1
     If WSforData <> "" Then
     ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WSforData).Range(CellforData).Offset(0, Col).Value = Recordset.Fields(Col).Name
     End If
 Next

' Write recordset
If WSforData <> "" Then
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WSforData).Range(CellforData).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset Recordset
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WSforData).Columns.AutoFit
End If
 End With

 ' Clear recordset and close connection
  Set Recordset = Nothing
 Connection.Close
 Set Connection = Nothing
 End Sub
```

This piece of the "DBLinks" worksheet is probably also needed for full understanding of the code:
[DBLinks user input area for database connectivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhgpJ.jpg)

**SOLUTION:**

I followed the advice to look into VBProject.VBComponents which copied the macro. I created a simple form which asked for the name to use for the macro and the rest of the inputs comes from the relative reference. I will spare you for a full copy of my long and less than graceful code, but the essential of the code are:

In case someone else could benefit from my experience: In the Click-action of the command button on the form:

```
Private Sub cmdCreateDB_Click()
'Go to Tools, References and add: Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3

Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
        Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
        Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
        Dim LineNum As Long
        Const DQUOTE = """" ' one " character

        Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")
        Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
        Dim txtDBLinkName As String
        txtDBLinkName = Me.txtDBName

        With CodeMod
            LineNum = .CountOfLines + 1
            .InsertLines LineNum, "     Sub " & txtDBLinkName & "()"
LineNum = LineNum + 1
.InsertLines LineNum, "     ' Click on Tools, References and select"
LineNum = LineNum + 1
.InsertLines LineNum, "     ' the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.0 Library"

' And then it goes on forever through all the lines of the original code...
' just remember to replace all double quotations with(Without Square brackets): 
' [" & DQUOTE & "]
'And it ends up with:

LineNum = LineNum + 1
.InsertLines LineNum, "       Set Recordset = Nothing"
LineNum = LineNum + 1
.InsertLines LineNum, "      Connection.Close"
LineNum = LineNum + 1
.InsertLines LineNum, "      Set Connection = Nothing"
LineNum = LineNum + 1
.InsertLines LineNum, "      End Sub"


        End With
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Thank you everyone for your help. - Especially you @findwindow for coming up with the path to a solution.

Comment: How about you create a form where you ask for the information needed to in that one line of code. Or.. you have them fill out the info in a seperate tab, and grab the values. Messing with VBA from within VBA is only going to lead to pain. Also, functions are going to be like a 1000 times easier to figure out then the route you are going.

Comment: I could do that, but how would that help create the new macro? - Then they would have to run that form every time they want to update the access data(?)... ok, your probably right. I'll try venturing Down the function-thought-path until something better shows up.

Comment: Try googling `VBProject.VBComponents`

Comment: I don't see how this can't be done by either passing an argument to the sub of using an `If` block. In any case, we need to at least see the code that you're trying to change.

Comment: findwindow - a quick search on VBProject.VBComponents looks like it could be a viable solution - It's new ground for me, though, so I'll have to dig into it before I know if it's a solution. Thanks in any case.

Comment: Woahhh - FYI This `Dim number1, number2, number3 as Integer` is ***not*** the same as `Dim number1 as Integer, number2 as Integer, number3 as Integer`.  It's equivalent to `Dim number1 as Variant, number2 as Variant, number3 as Integer`.  If you don't give a type after *each* declaration, it's going to be `Variant`.  (A quick tip, you can do `Dim myString$` instead of `Dim myString as String`, and `Dim myNumber&` for `as Long` (see [here](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/50571-other-way-to-declare-variables-using-symbols/) for more)).

Comment: Sure but as JNevill says, it's not pretty.

Comment: @ BruceWayne - I know, but it Works, so why fix it?

Comment: I think it would be better to have them enter the information in a form or cells and have the information stored. You could simply ask if they want to change db's, tables, etc when they do any kind of update. If no, reuse info. If yes, call a form and change. Let the same macro do the heavy lifting and have them change only what they need when they need it. Otherwise, any updates will be hell.

Comment: @Trial N' Error Because integers are smaller variables than variants and it is a better practice to strongly type your variables.

Comment: @asp8811 - that could Work, but it would kind of, if not defeat, then cripple the purpose of making updates easier for the end-user, since sharing the file would require instructions on using the update form. But I'll mark it as a solution to explore though.

Comment: @asp8811 - point taken.

Comment: If you stored the information in a header row in the worksheet, you could do an automated check. The user could update or leave the information without ever being asked. You could even use data validation to make drop downs. If you really want to let them make connections by making macros, use a short macro that does nothing but call the one doing all of the work and pass the necessary variables to it. It's like a function, but not.

Comment: @findwindow  Thx for the hint - It Works with ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module").CodeModule which allows me to insert the macro. And thanks to every one else for your contributions!

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

**For the sake of completion, here's how this could be dealt with without [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming).**

Problems that boil down to *"do the same thing - but..."* can often be solved by making the program as generic as possible. All data specific to a single use-case should be passed down from above in a clear manner, allowing the program to be reused.

Let's look at an example of how this could be implemented in order to generate query strings from one or many ranges of varying sizes.

---

The first step is to group all data that belongs to the concept of a `Filter`. Since VBA doesn't have object literals, we can use an Array, a Collection or a Type to represent a Filter instead.

Generating the query strings requires distinction between *QueryFilters* and *RecordFilters*. Looking at the code, the two variants are similar enough to be handled by a simple Boolean within a single Type.

```
Option Explicit

Private Type Filter
    Field As String
    Operator As String
    Criteria As Variant
    AdditionalMethod As String
    ExtractedFields As String
    IsQueryFilter As Boolean
    FilterString As String
End Type
```

Now we can use a single variable instead of keeping track of multiple variables to represent a single concept.

One way a Filter can be generated is by using a Range.

```
' Generates a Filter from a given Range of input data.
Private Function GenerateFilter(ByRef source As Range) As Filter
    With GenerateFilter
        .Field = CStr(source)
        .Operator = CStr(source.Offset(0, 1))
        .Criteria = source.Offset(0, 2)
        .AdditionalMethod = CStr(source.Offset(0, 3))
        .ExtractedFields = CStr(source.Offset(0, 4))
        .IsQueryFilter = CBool(source.Offset(0, 5))
        .FilterString = GenerateFilterString(GenerateFilter)
    End With
End Function
```

Just as a single concept can be declared as a Type, a group of things can be declared as an Array (or a Collection, Dictionary, ...). This is useful, as it lets us decouple the logic from a specific Range.

```
' Generates a Filter for each row of a given Range of input data.
Private Function GenerateFilters(ByRef source As Range) As Filter()
    Dim filters() As Filter
    Dim filterRow As Range
    Dim i As Long

    ReDim filters(0 To source.Rows.Count)
    i = 0

    For Each filterRow In source.Rows
        filters(i) = GenerateFilter(filterRow)
        i = i + 1
    Next

    GenerateFilters = filters()
End Function
```

We now have a function that can return an Array of Filters from a given Range - and, as long as the columns are laid down in the right order, the code will work just fine with any Range.

With all of the data in a convenient package, it's easy enough to assemble the `FilterString`.

```
' Generates a FilterString for a given Filter.
Private Function GenerateFilterString(ByRef aFilter As Filter) As String
    Dim temp As String

    temp = " "

    With aFilter
        If .AdditionalMethod <> "" Then temp = temp & .AdditionalMethod & " "

        If .IsQueryFilter Then
            temp = temp & "[" & .Field & "]"
        Else
            temp = temp & .Field
        End If

        temp = temp & " " & .Operator & " "

        If VarType(.Criteria) = vbString Then
            temp = temp & "'" & .Criteria & "'"
        Else
            temp = temp & .Criteria
        End If
    End With

    GenerateFilterString = temp
End Function
```

The data can then be merged to strings that can be used in queries regardless of how many Filters of either type are present in the specified Range.

```
' Merges the FilterStrings of Filters that have IsQueryString set as True.
Private Function MergeQueryFilterStrings(ByRef filters() As Filter) As String
    Dim temp As String
    Dim i As Long

    temp = " WHERE"

    For i = 0 To UBound(filters)
        If filters(i).IsQueryFilter Then temp = temp & filters(i).FilterString
    Next

    MergeQueryFilterStrings = temp
End Function

' Merges the FilterStrings of Filters that have IsQueryString set as False.
Private Function MergeRecordFilterStrings(ByRef filters() As Filter) As String
    Dim temp As String
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To UBound(filters)
        If Not filters(i).IsQueryFilter Then _
            temp = temp & filters(i).FilterString
    Next

    MergeRecordFilterStrings = temp
End Function

' Merges the ExtractedFields of all Filters.
Private Function MergeExtractedFields(ByRef filters() As Filter) As String
    Dim temp As String
    Dim i As Long

    temp = ""

    For i = 0 To UBound(filters)
        If filters(i).ExtractedFields <> "" Then _
            temp = temp & "[" & filters(i).ExtractedFields & "],"
    Next

    If temp = "" Then
        temp = "*"
    Else
        temp = Left(temp, Len(temp) - 1) ' Remove dangling comma.
    End If

    MergeExtractedFields = temp
End Function
```

---

With all of that done, we can finally plug a single Range in and get the generated strings out. It would be trivial to change `filterRange` or generate Filters from multiple Ranges.

```
Public Sub TestStringGeneration()
    Dim filters() As Filter
    Dim filterRange As Range

    Set filterRange = Range("A1:A10")

    filters = GenerateFilters(filterRange)

    Debug.Print MergeQueryFilterStrings(filters)
    Debug.Print MergeRecordFilterStrings(filters)
    Debug.Print MergeExtractedFields(filters)
End Sub
```

---

**TL;DR**

- Split code to reusable Functions & Subs
- Favor sending data as arguments
- Avoid hard-coding
- Group data that represent a single concept
- Use Arrays or other data structures over multiple variables

---

Comment: Thank you for the lesson - I will implement those functions as well. If my code is the drawing of a 4-year old, then you just turned it into a Picasso. Although it doesn't directly address the initial issue, it definetly simplifies and makes the solution alot more professional, when combined with the VBProject.VBComponents part.